# How to add the new theme with out FTP in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, ftp

I am new in wordpress.  Now i have no FTP Details (just working in my local system). I can not add the new theme (not default theme) without FTP details. Is there any option to add theme without FTP.

/***** below the details displayed ****/
Connection Information

To perform the requested action, WordPress needs to access your web server. Please enter your FTP credentials to proceed. If you do not remember your credentials, you should contact your web host.

Hostname 
FTP Username 
FTP Password This password will not be stored on the server.
Connection Type

Connection Type  FTP      FTPS (SSL)

Comment: Can you access wp-admin you can add new theme in appearance section  or you can manually extract the theme and place it wp-content/themes folder  .

Comment: No need of File Transfer "Protocol" when you can do it yourself by copying and pasting using GUI.

Comment: Hi . sry i am not clear. I will go to appearance -> themes -> add new theme. And see the more theme, Here no option to download the theme. right ? How to copy the theme to my theme folder?

Answer (score 1):

when working on your local system, just copy the theme-folder into wp-content\themes and activate it in your WP - Backend

Comment: Hi . sry i am not clear. I will go to appearance -> themes -> add new theme.  And see the more theme, Here no option to download the theme. right ? How to copy the theme to my theme folder?

Comment: when you see the themes, inside the theme boxes there are 2 buttons on the bottom of the box, preview and install. What happens if you click on install?

Comment: Yes . I click the install button means redirect to connect information page(FTP details page)

Answer (score 1):

```
You can upload from admin side.
Follow this steps

1) Go to Appearance > Themes
2) Click on Add New options
3) click on Upload Theme option.
4) Select your theme zip folder and install.

I hope it will work for you
```

Comment: okay. As for understand,  we can not install the theme directly without FTP. just download the theme in any other site and upload or directly copy to theme folder. right ?